# Botched Python install on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (can't import MySQL)

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am a beginner programmer trying to learn python. I made the smart move to Ubuntu, but being unfamiliar with this OS environment I believe I botched the install of Python.

I have installed VIM and MySQL. They are both installed correctly. VIM works correctly with Python, but MySQL does not.

When I try to import MySQL into python I get:

```
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

I believe that my PATH setup is wrong with Python. I have tried to uninstall and reinstall. Someone said it might be that I have Python 2.7.5 installed when I need 2.7.3 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Here is my sys.path

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['', '/home/allen/lib/python', '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages'
```

I wish I could fix this on my own, I have been searching online with no success. Thanks in advance for any help. It's very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you installed `MySQLdb` or did you install `MySQL`?

Comment: I used sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb

Comment: This is what I get when typing apt -cache show python-mysqldb http://paste.pound-python.org/show/2Bi3aIibeeekwu8fmR9O/

Comment: Probably you want to try the packaged python 2.7.3 from 12.04 LTS instead of a self installed 2.7.5. In general, it's best to use the apt toolchain for package management whenever possible. Though for software development it's not always possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to  install mySql-Python as you need the python bindings to import.